# find duplicate record in BODI

Tags: sql, unique

I am loading a file data into a table using BODI (Business Objects Data Integrator).
Unfortunately the input file has a duplicate record which is giving unique constraint error while inserting in the table. Is there a way to find that duplicate record?

Answer (score 0):

import into table with the constraint disabled or removed or table with similar structure without the constraint and do the query

```
select uniquefield(s) from tablename group by uniquefield(s) having count(*) > 1
```

and sometimes the error message shows the key that is duplicate too.

Comment: your query is used to find the duplicates in a table. But in my case, the table unique constraints wont allow the record to be inserted itself

Comment: disable the constraint temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use a table compare transformation and set the field "Input Contains DUplicate Keys" . This will load the the record only once even though the source field has duplicate records.